# Extend the possible types of values of dictionary in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dictionary, strong-typing, typescript4.0

I have a strongly-typed style object in my React Native project in TypeScript:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    flex: 1
  },
});
```

This works as normal as `StyleSheet.create` expects arbitrary named keys with the target values of `ViewStyle`, `TextStyle`, and `ImageStyle` as defined below:

```
export namespace StyleSheet {
    type NamedStyles<T> = { [P in keyof T]: ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle };

    /**
     * Creates a StyleSheet style reference from the given object.
     */
    export function create<T extends NamedStyles<T> | NamedStyles<any>>(styles: T | NamedStyles<T>): T;
    [...]
}
```

`container` is an arbitrary key, and `backgroundColor` is defined in `ViewStyle` to have a value of the type `ColorValue`, which is defined as `string | OpaqueColorValue` where `OpaqueColorValue` is a unique symbol.

However, I'm building a function that I want to feed with the following type signature wherever `ColorValue` was previously accepted in original type:

`ColorValue | { light: ColorValue, dark: ColorValue }`

Along with a parameter named either `light` or `dark` supplied to my function, I will use it like:

```
const styles = myFunction({
  container:{
    backgroundColor: {
      light: 'red',
      dark: 'blue'
    },
    flex: 1
  },
}, 'dark');
```

And it will pick the appropriate key, e.g. it will return:

```
{
    container:{
      backgroundColor: 'blue' //as we picked the 'dark' key from original input
      flex: 1
    }
}
```

In plain English, I want my function's input type to accept anything that `StyleSheet.create` accepts, and *in addition to that*, also accept `{light: ColorValue, dark: ColorValue}` wherever  it accepted `ColorValue`. It then picks the appropriate keys, then calls `StyleSheet.create` internally and returns the result.

I wrote the function and it works, but I'm struggling to make it accept objects with the `light/dark` keys in IntelliSense and linter (of course, without casting to `any` or `unknown`).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is this question specific to React?  If not you might want to take out the example code's dependence on it to constitute a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?)

Comment: Or, if the question is specific to React, you might want to tag it as such

Comment: @jcalz nope it's a TypeScript issue, React is just utilizing it. i'll try to provide an MCVE now update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might benefit from having a few [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types), [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) like this:

```
type DeepReplaceSupertype<T, S, D> = [S] extends [T] ? D : {
    [K in keyof T]: DeepReplaceSupertype<T[K], S, D>
}

type DeepReplaceSubtype<T, S, D> = [T] extends [S] ? D : {
    [K in keyof T]: DeepReplaceSubtype<T[K], S, D>
}
```

The idea is that `DeepReplaceSupertype<T, S, D>` takes a type `T`, a source type `S`, and a destination type `D` and it checks: if `S` is assignable to `T`, then replace it with `D`.  Otherwise, walk down recursively through `T` and replace all properties and subproperties the same way. `DeepReplaceSubtype<T, S, D>` is similar but it checks if `T` is assignable to `S`.

Then your function's signature could look like this:

```
interface Shade { light: ColorValue, dark: ColorValue }

export declare function myFunction<
    T extends DeepReplaceSupertype<NamedStyles<any>, ColorValue, Shade>>(
        styles: T, shade: 'light' | 'dark'
    ): DeepReplaceSubtype<T, Shade, ColorValue>;
```

Meaning: accept anything of type `T` where you take that `NameStyles` and replace subproperties that accept `ColorValue` and change them to `Shade`.  And then, the return value should take `T` and replace any subproperties that are a subtype of `Shade` and turn them back to `ColorValue`.  It should work like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.myFunction({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: {
            light: 'red',
            dark: 'blue'
        },
        flex: 1
    },
}, 'dark');

/* const styles: {
    container: {
        backgroundColor: ColorValue;
        flex: number;
    };
} */
```

Looks like what you want, I think.  You might be able to get even more clever and have the output type be specifically the type of the value picked from `light` or `dark` (so `string` instead of `ColorValue`), but that would be more complicated and probably not necessary, so I'll stop there.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgNWAUwO4GUYE8A2aANHACpoAeMOBxcAkiAIYDmaNhJAwhPtMk3wBXNHAC+cAGZQIIOAHIoaJgGMYAWgB2TGMABuaeQCgTlSLDjaQaAM5hVojuwAWaNPAQmTcH3DxhRABE3MAAlNDB8BywhANhcAIAeUhIsEkCAPjgAXjgAbSwAXThKGDRNABMbfNJigH44QLgALkQjXw78gGk4YE04AGs0XAhJMkLW4IjwyOjYtHik0jyuwtT0jPbfMW9ffyCQmaiVdiEAI33k9cas3LzakqpyqvyiuAam1s9O3xXe-qGIzGtUmhwix1OFwSaGSKzWcDSNy2Ph2ux8+zgADkmNYKk4bMlboh8gAFf6DYajcatVCYJxwAA+ZFK9KZjFY7DwhHEAG40Y9zPAKmgVFElFIhJo1MAIP0VEodDDSI8ypVqtjcfjEkxNLgMhkABQ2Lm2VqkACUZr5yP+ZSgkgcCOcTGFxPwwBYzhgrR4fCgAmEdAqTCgAx9vH4ghE4n5ZmgQpFYtEkkl0tlcBAuAAYqndLLEjaOsrSs9qlMwuC5nFLhq0HiTQSdXruBH-VG6FhncL9QbCz84MbaDYzSQbF20K15O7PTB5IyFMHQ8Z+3BLY0wbMTjEoUtUuOW36AyIMtbUSYVLLjQOGzkESbO24YAA6TM5qV5zQG76+C+aGBMPoFi+PsfDOVQBhYGRJQqX1oGAlcOmnL1JyUCp5CIEDOkXMMFDOQNl37MQMJXSRCAoVoAEYbSIowiIXEMBnkc1rQAegAKjgX8r0HQhhzaDpf3-QCoHg-swJUCCoMqWCRLgGSjzQPkSLI1pNCEEAzgWJTtj5CQ2JYoA)